# what is the importance of apigroups in kubernetes role definition

Tags: kubernetes

Could some one please help me with this..
I would like to understand a bit about the apiGroups & its usage in below Role definition.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: example.com-superuser  
rules:
- apiGroups: ["example.com"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

I was going through RBAC in Kubernetes. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/
Above example is from this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An api group groups a set of resource types in a common namespace. For example, resource types related to Ingress services are grouped under the `networking.k8s.io` api group:

```
$ kubectl api-resources --api-group newtorking.k8s.io
NAME              SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION             NAMESPACED   KIND
ingressclasses                 networking.k8s.io/v1   false        IngressClass
ingresses         ing          networking.k8s.io/v1   true         Ingress
networkpolicies   netpol       networking.k8s.io/v1   true         NetworkPolicy
```

It is possible to have two different resource types that have the same short name in different resource groups. For example, in my OpenShift system there are two different groups that provide a `Subscription` resource type:

```
$ kubectl api-resources | awk '$NF == "Subscription" {print}'
subscriptions                         appsub                                 apps.open-cluster-management.io/v1                 true         Subscription
subscriptions                         sub,subs                               operators.coreos.com/v1alpha1                      true         Subscription
```

If I am creating a role, I need to specify to *which* `Subscription` I want to grant access. This:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: allow-config-access
rules:
- apiGroups:
    - operators.coreos.com
  resources:
    - subscriptions
  verbs: ["*"]
```

Provides access to different resources than this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: allow-config-access
rules:
- apiGroups:
    - apps.open-cluster-management.io
  resources:
    - subscriptions
  verbs: ["*"]
```

Answer (score 1):

ApiGroups in Kubernetes are used to specify the set of resources that a Role or ClusterRole can access. In the example given, apiGroups is set to ["example.com"] which means the Role is allowed to access all resources from the “example.com” api. This allows admins to control access to different resources within the Kubernetes cluster.